# how to write a regular expression to match series based on year range?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find matching year from a series id starting with 201x and 202x from file . I was thinking to solve this problem with a regex in order to extract match paterns

the following file contains an sample of my original file

```
NE112040
ENE112042
ENE112043
ENE112009
ENE112006
ENE112041
ENE112012
ENE112018
MEC112129
INF112094
2012030116
2012030395
2012030396
2012030364
2012030246
```

code to match numbers

```
def getNumbers(str): 
    array = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str) 
    return array
```

once I found the matching patterns , I have to save into a new file with matching series

Comment: Why regex? Why not just `val.startswith("201")`?

Comment: 201x to 202x which means 2010,2011,2012, etc to 2021,2022 etc

Comment: So you'll get all of them if you read file row-by-row (as strings) and do `res = row.startswith('201') + row.startswith('202')`

Answer (score 1):

`len(val) >= 4 and val[3].isdigit() and (val.startswith('201') or val.startswith('202'))`

And if you prefer regex anyway:

`re.match('(201|202)\d', val)`